# What are all the possible assert functions?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I don't see the possible assert functions in [protractor's api](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api). Could someone post the possible functions to use?

I know of:

- toEqual
- toBeLessThan

**Example**

```
expect(element.getText()).toEqual('Please help me!'); //toEqual being the assertion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are provided by *an* expectation/assertion library to determine the 'result' of a testable operation. By itself, protractor merely provides the glue/harness for Angular-Selenium (to run within a testing framework) that exposes testable operations.

In this case that could be [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect). (See the link for standard expectations.)

> When you use `expect`, you write assertions similarly to how you would say them, e.g. "I expect this value to be equal to 3" or "I expect this array to contain 3"..

Answer (score 1):

`Protractor` itself has nothing to do with the assertions that you do via `expect()`. This is a ["Test Framework"'s responsibility](http://www.protractortest.org/#/frameworks). By default, `Protractor` has [`Jasmine` test framework](http://jasmine.github.io/) enabled (but you can choose a different one, like `Mocha` or `Cucumber` - this part is configurable). Here is the related documentation page describing what matchers are built into `Jasmine`:

- [Expectations](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Expectations)

`Jasmine` allows to create [custom matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/custom_matcher.html) as well.

Also, there is a [`jasmine-matchers` third-party library](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) that provides a lot of extra matchers that can be handy during test automation.